# ActiveMQ: New consumer of virtual queue receives already consumed messages

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I do not understand the behavior of virtual topics in context of consumer of the same virtual destination going up and down:

**Workflow/ Situation**

1. Create virtual topic => *Virtual.A*
2. Create Consumer1 of virtual queue ("Consumer group 1") => *Consumer.**CG1**.Virtual.A*
3. Create Producer1 and sent message to *Virtual.A* => Message1
4. Consumer1 receives and ACKs Message1
5. Shutdown Consumer1
6. Create Consumer2 to virtual queue ("Consumer group 1") => *Consumer.**CG1**.Virtual.A*

**Observed behavior**

- Consumer2 receives Message1 again
- If there are multiple message, Consumer2 receives all of them
- If Consumer2 is created while Consumer1 is still up, it still receives all of the messages

**Expectation**

I would have expected that new consumers of the same virtual queue will only receive new messages, not all of them again.

**Question**

- I am looking for an explanation or a reference to the documentation that explains that particular behavior.
- Is there a way to prevent this behavior and make ActiveMQ only sent the unconsumed message of the virtual queue?
- What will be the size of the resent history? Will it always be everything the virtual topic still holds?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's worth noting that "virtual topics" in ActiveMQ "Classic" is an ActiveMQ-specific way to solve a problem which is solved by the shared subscription feature introduced in JMS 2. ActiveMQ "Classic" doesn't yet support JMS 2, but [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) does. If you want the lock-in inherent in provider-specific features and get this functionality in a standard, portable way then you might consider migrating to ActiveMQ Artemis. To be clear, it is slated to become the next major version of ActiveMQ.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. We are using AmazonMQ which is not supporting Artemis (yet).

Answer (score 0):

This is related to a configuration issue.

The session was set to CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE, but the consumer did not respect the flag.

After fixing this issue, the behavior is as expected: Only not acknowledge messages are sent to new consumers.